# Which one of those will charge my battery faster? Current or power?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current

If I have 2 sockets:

1. One supplies 220V, 3A, 660 watts (more current but less power)
2. One supplies 400V, 2A, 800 watts (more power but less current)

Which one will charge faster my battery from 0% to 100%?

Comment: Sockets? The battery _charger_ will ultimately determine how fast your battery is being charged and your outlet/socket needs to provide enough power and the correct voltage according to your charger's input requirements.

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you specific what is the battery you are talking about, and what those sockets are (i.e. what they are connected to).

Answer (score 4):

If you connect your battery direcly to your sockets, then you will destroy your battery.

If you connect a proper battery charger, then it mainly depends on the charger (a 500 W charger will never provide more than 500 W to the battery, whatever you connect it to.) Basically, the more powerful the charger, the faster you charge. Please note however that your charger must accept the rated voltage (some chargers might work both with 220 V and 400 V, but most will not.) Also note that it is a very bad idea to connect a charger more powerful (or drawing more current) than what the socket can supply: at best you blow your fuse, at worst your wires catch fire.

Also note that a charger is a voltage converter, so the input current itself doesn't determine the charging speed: it is its power (and its efficiency) that determine the charging (output) current.

For chargers below 660 W, you don't care if they are 220 V or 400 V (you just have to plug them on the right socket.) If you can find a 400 V charger with power between 660 and 800 W, then it will be even faster. A 220 V above 660 W or a 400 V above 800 W is useless.

Please also check how fast you can charge your battery (not all batteries can withstand a 800 W charging.) Also note that usually, the faster you charge a battery, the more you shorten its life. How fast charging is OK greatly depends on the technology. It can be like 0.1C charging (i.e. current =1/10th of capacity) or 5C (for some special fast recharge lithium batteries.)